# Can I change a custom SPContentType's display name?

Tags: content-type, display-name

I created a SPContentType of my own. In the Sharepoint Site Settings I see all the default content types with names in my language (polish). How can I change display names for my own content types?

When I wanted to create my own SPContentType inheriting from "Item" I needed to use the English/internal name of the SPContentType "Item", not the polish name "Element", so I suppose there must be a way to add my own display name for a SPContentType. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can it..

There is a properties available of content type..

Like SPContentType.Name

pls refer below link..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttype_members.aspx

Comment: My pleasure.. wc :D